# MCNPX for nuclear simulation

Tags: algorithms

is it legal here to ask this problem?
I need someone help. 
I run mcnpx. I try to calculate f4:n using nps:1000. But, it stop directly before culculate f4. There is comment: stack trace terminated abnormally. And there is warning: cross-section file xsdir and bertin does not exist. 
Anyone can help what the problem in my work? I appreciated every suggestion. Thanks. Rose

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE! It is legal to ask here, but probably not very useful. If you have problems with a specific software, it's much better to ask the developers about it. Maybe this mailing list can help: https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/mcnp_forum.shtml

Comment: Questions about possible bugs in a particular software package (or even just how to use the package) aren't appropriate for Computational Science unless they're presented in the broader context of how to solve a scientific problem.  There are usually more appropriate mailing lists or web sites for asking questions specific to a particular software package.

Comment: Of course, the very first suggestion is always to read the error message: "warning: cross-section file xsdir and bertin does not exist". If MCNP expects these files and they're not there, then where are they and what happens if you provide them?

Comment: @Rose: contact someone in your organisation who has experience with the code. Normally, the official RSICC or OECD/NEA liaison officer (the person in your organisation who signed for you to obtain the code and its license) should be your first contact. She/he will be able to either help you or put you into contact with more experienced MCNPX users in your organisation.